# Having trouble Deploying Build in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to create a build agent in Visual Studio 2015. I have TFS 2015, and Visual Studio 2015 installed on my Windows 8 laptop. This is for my learning. I have been following the [steps in link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows):

However, after Step 6, the command line complains that I do not have appropriate permissions.

My user I am logged in as has Admin rights on the box, is part of the Agent Pool Administrators and Agent Pool Service Accounts.

After the build agent is created, it has a Red color next to it showing offline. I am not sure how or have been unsuccessful in turning it to green.

[image]

Thoughts?

Thank you. 
Sam

Comment: It should turn green within 1 or 2 seconds after creation. Check the logs in the "_diag" folder. You will find the error there.

Comment: Can you provide the error dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to run the agent with admin privileges.  You may need to start CMD as admin before attempting to run ConfigureAgent.

Answer (score 0):

Check the account that is running your build agent service to see whether this account belongs to Build Agent Service Accounts group.